# How to check which module db updates have been applied?

Tags: database, 9

For a specific module, how can I check which database updates have been applied in Drupal 9?  I've downloaded a database from a server and I want to check what the current module schema is.

[In Drupal 7, this was in the `system` database table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014864), but that no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For Drupal 9.3+/10:

`drush php-eval "echo \Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->getInstalledVersion('mymodule');"`

Source: [Change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2444417)

#### For Drupal 8/9 up to 9.3:

`drush php-eval "echo drupal_get_installed_schema_version('mymodule');"`

Source: [gist](https://www.gistshare.com/notes/98/how-check-current-schema-version-module-drupal)

Comment: Check the API documentation - drupal_get_installed_schema_version() is deprecated in Drupal 9 and will be removed in Drupal 10. If you use the recommended replacement now, you won't have to make any changes to this code in the future.

Comment: @anonymous Thanks, updated!